# How do you join tables from disparate databases in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Put simply, I know how to join different tables in SQL from the same database, but how do you join accross databases to CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW? This would be really helpful, as I'm sure other pepole would have the same question. Thanks.

Comment: are the databases on the same server?

Answer (score 2):

If the databases are on same servers then you can access another database from a database through that database name if you have granted permission on that database.

syntax is very simple to access object from another database `databasename.schema.object_name`

If database name is database1, schema name is sch and the table you are trying to access is table1 then it will be

```
select * from database1.sch.table1
```

Here is a view created on database3 combining tables from database1, database2 and database3.

```
create secure view database3.sch.view3 as
select view1.id as view1id, table2.id as table2id, table3.id as table3id
from database1.sch.view1 view1,
     database2.sch.table2 table2,
     database3.sch.table3 table3;
```

Please look into this documentation for further clarification.

[Sharing Data from Multiple Databases](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-mutiple-db.html)